# What is the simplest way to have futanari-type genitalia?

Tags: anatomy

A futanari is defined as a humanoid with both a functional penis and a
functional vagina. What is the most human-like way such an arrangement of structures could develop?

Comment: Beyond Japan, the term has come to be used to describe a commonly pornographic genre of eroge, manga, and anime which includes characters that show primary sexual characteristics from both females and males. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futanari)

Comment: Is your question about true hermaphroditism, or just genitalia?

Comment: @Alexander It's just about the genitalia

Comment: How functional should both organs be? Is this humanoid infertile (with one or both organs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way, overall, would be for the primordial phallus to pause development, and for the urogenital opening to speed up, so that the primordial phallus can form around the urethra to become a penis. The penis would also need to grow into the body like a clitoris, for the sake of the vagina. The prostate would form around the urethra, and connect to the vas deferens, which link to the ovotestes, which would be in the usual female place. The rest of the genitals should be able to form in the usual female way.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [intersex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex)

> Intersex people are individuals born with any of several sex characteristics including chromosome patterns, gonads, or genitals that, according to the Office of the United Nations High Commissioner for Human Rights, "do not fit typical binary notions of male or female bodies". Though the range of atypical sex characteristics may be obvious from birth through the presence of physically ambiguous genitalia, in other instances, atypical characteristics may go unnoticed, presenting as ambiguous internal reproductive organs or atypical chromosomes that may remain unknown to an individual all of their life.

> The notion of intersex individuals can be understood in the context of sexual system biology that varies across different types of organisms. Most animal species (~95%, including humans) are gonochoric, in which individuals are of either a female or male sex. Hermaphroditic species (some animals and most flowering plants) are represented by individuals that can express both sexes simultaneously or sequentially across their lifetime. Intersex individuals in a number of gonochoric species, who express both female and male phenotypic characters to some degree, are known to exist at very low prevalences.
>
> Although "hermaphrodite" and "intersex" have been used synonymously in humans, a hermaphrodite is specifically an individual capable of producing female and male gametes. While there are reports of individuals that seemed to have the potential to produce both types of gamete, other sources have stated that there is no known case of a human hermaphrodite since both female and male reproduction have not been observed in the same individual.
>
> There are a variety of symptoms that can occur. Ambiguous genitalia is the most common sign. There can be micropenis, clitoromegaly, partial labial fusion, electrolyte abnormalities, delayed or absent puberty, unexpected changes at puberty, hypospadias, labial or inguinal (groin) masses (which may turn out to be testes) in girls and undescended testes (which may turn out to be ovaries) in boys.
>
> Ambiguous genitalia may appear as a large clitoris or as a small penis. Because there is variation in all of the processes of the development of the sex organs, a child can be born with a sexual anatomy that is typically female or feminine in appearance with a larger-than-average clitoris (clitoral hypertrophy) or typically male or masculine in appearance with a smaller-than-average penis that is open along the underside. The appearance may be quite ambiguous, describable as female genitals with a very large clitoris and partially fused labia, or as male genitals with a very small penis, completely open along the midline ("hypospadic"), and empty scrotum. Fertility is variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the Nebula-award-winning novel [3212](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2312_(novel)), it was deliberately genetically engineered.  If you're asking about future humans in particular, that seems to be the only way.  In that novel, the motivations for making people this was that it is one of several mods that promotes longevity.

For aliens, it would probably develop from phylum that are hermaphrodites, as are their ancestors all the way back to worms.  (As are Earthworms today, BTW.)  So they would not have one embryonic thing that differentiated into either male or female parts; they would have two different things that may have started out as two copies of the same structure but have since evolved independently.

In their evolution, the early multi-cellular animals would have maintained the ability to act as both male and female, rather than choosing one (note that in some animals its *one at a time* but the individual can switch during its life).  I expect this would mean there is a general lack of **dimorphism**, so individuals don't specialize into different forms.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you mean today, you can create sexual organs from the printer, I don't know how effective it will be and there is also a case of a man who was born without a penis and he was artificially created one, he could even become erect.